# TableView dynamic height problem inside a Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView in tableViewCell with dynamic height together with other ui components having dynamic height & proportinal width to the cell. Problem:  inner tableViewCells shrinks when rendered & scrolling outer uitableview. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import SVProgressHUD

class DashboardProgramcell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
```

Data, models here..

```
    public var icerikModel:WMPIcerikModel?
    static let ID:String = "DashboardProgramcell"
    static let turCellPair = (tur: TurID.Program, cellId: ID)


    var kListData: WMPArrayOfKatilimciModel?
```

Cell subViews..

```
    //MainContainer
    var container: UIView = {
        var container = UIView()
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return container
    }()


    //Left side
    var leftContainer: UIView = {
        var leftContainer = UIView()
        leftContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return leftContainer
    }()

    var gSaat: UILabel = {
        var gSaat = UILabel()
        gSaat.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        gSaat.numberOfLines = 0
        gSaat.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
        return gSaat
    }()

    var sure: UILabel = {
        var sure = UILabel()
        sure.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sure.numberOfLines = 0
        sure.backgroundColor = ColorHelper.mercury
        sure.textAlignment = .center
        sure.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
        return sure
    }()


    var ptad: UITextView = {
        var ptad = UITextView()
        ptad.textColor = .white
        ptad.textAlignment = .center
        ptad.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        ptad.isScrollEnabled = false
        ptad.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        ptad.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
        ptad.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        ptad.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        return ptad
    }()



    //Right part
    var rightContainer: UIView = {
        var rightContainer = UIView()
        rightContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return rightContainer
    }() 


    var rightTopTextView: UILabel = {
        var rightTopTextView = UILabel()
        rightTopTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        rightTopTextView.numberOfLines = 0
        rightTopTextView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        rightTopTextView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        rightTopTextView.backgroundColor = ColorHelper.arzPopup
        return rightTopTextView
    }()
```

Here is the inner tableView and its constraints!

```
    var kList: UITableView = {
        var kList = UITableView()
        kList.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        kList.bounces = false
        kList.bouncesZoom = false
        kList.alwaysBounceVertical = false
        kList.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        kList.tag = KListCell.TAG
        kList.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        kList.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        kList.register(KListCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: KListCell.ID)
        kList.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        return kList
    }()

    var kListHeightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?
    var rTopTextViewHeightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?
```

Constructor & constraint activation!

```
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.tag = TurID.Program.rawValue
        self.selectionStyle = .none 
        self.addSubview(container)

        container.addSubview(leftContainer) //OK
        container.addSubview(rightContainer) //OK
        leftContainer.addSubview(gSaat) //OK
        leftContainer.addSubview(sure) //OK
        leftContainer.addSubview(ptad)
        rightContainer.addSubview(rightTopTextView)
        rightContainer.addSubview(kList)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            container.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 2),
            container.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -2),
            container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 2),
            container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -2),

            leftContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor),
            leftContainer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leftAnchor),
            leftContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor),
            leftContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.30),
            leftContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor),
            leftContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.leftAnchor),

            rightContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor),
            rightContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor),
            rightContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.68),
            rightContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor),
            rightContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.rightAnchor),

            gSaat.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftContainer.topAnchor, constant: 4),
            gSaat.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 4),
            gSaat.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -4),
            gSaat.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sure.topAnchor, constant: -2),

            sure.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 4),
            sure.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -4),
            sure.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ptad.topAnchor, constant:-2),

            ptad.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 4),
            ptad.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftContainer.rightAnchor),
            ptad.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: leftContainer.bottomAnchor),
            ptad.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),

            rightTopTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.topAnchor, constant:4),
            rightTopTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.leftAnchor, constant:4),
            rightTopTextView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.rightAnchor, constant:-4),
            rightTopTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: kList.topAnchor),

            kList.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.leftAnchor, constant:2),
            kList.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.rightAnchor, constant:-2),
            kList.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.bottomAnchor, constant:-2)

        ])

        container.addBorders(edges: [.left, .right, .bottom], color: ColorHelper.programBg, width: 1)

        kList.dataSource = self
        kList.delegate = self

//        kListHeightConstraint = kList.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
//        kListHeightConstraint?.isActive = true

//        rTopTextViewHeightConstraint = rightTopTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120)
//        rTopTextViewHeightConstraint?.isActive = true

        self.rightTopTextView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapItself)))
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    @objc func tapItself()
    {
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            SoapService(vc: self.viewControllerForTableView!).KayitDetay(tur: self.icerikModel!.TID!, kayitID: self.icerikModel!.ID!)
        }
    }



    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }

    public func adjustSubViews()
    {
         DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let icerik = self.icerikModel {

                //Left
                self.gSaat.text = icerik.GSaat ?? ""
                self.sure.text = icerik.Sure ?? ""
                self.ptad.text = icerik.PTAD ?? ""
                self.ptad.backgroundColor = self.ptad.text.isEmpty ? UIColor.clear : (self.ptad.text.hasPrefix("Arz") || self.ptad.text.hasPrefix("arz") ? TurID.Arz.tableviewBg() : TurID.Ziyaret.tableviewBg())

                //Right
                if let ack = icerik.Ack
                {
                    self.rightTopTextView.attributedText = ack.convertHTML().convertHtmlAttributed()
//                    self.rTopTextViewHeightConstraint?.constant = self.rightTopTextView.contentSize.height
                }
                else
                {
                    self.rightTopTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
                }

                if let KListe = icerik.KListe, KListe.count != 0 {
                    self.kListData = KListe
                    self.kList.reloadData()
                }
                else
                {
//                    self.kListHeightConstraint?.constant = 5
                    SVProgressHUD.dismissMainUI { }
                }

                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let _kListData = self.kListData, _kListData.count != 0 {
            return _kListData.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    var kTVHeight:CGFloat = 0

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let kListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: KListCell.ID)  as!  KListCell
        if let _kListData = self.kListData , _kListData.count != 0 {
            kListCell.katilimciModel = _kListData[indexPath.row]
            kListCell.adjustSubViews()
//            self.kTVHeight += kListCell.frame.height
            if indexPath.row == _kListData.count - 1 && kTVHeight > 10
            {
//                kListHeightConstraint?.constant = kTVHeight
//                rTopTextViewHeightConstraint?.constant = rightTopTextView.contentSize.height
//                kTVHeight = 0
            }
        }
        return kListCell
    }


    //If we got cell to display this func will work!
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if tableView.visibleCells.count == 0 {
            SVProgressHUD.dismissMainUI {  }
        }
    }




}//class DashboardProgramcell

class  KListCell: UITableViewCell {

    var katilimciModel:WMPKatilimciModel?
    static let ID:String = "KListCell"
    static let TAG = 4001

    //MainContainer
    var container: UIView = {
        var container = UIView()
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return container
    }()


    //Left side
    var leftContainer: UIView = {
        var leftContainer = UIView()
        leftContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return leftContainer
    }()

    //Right part
    var rightContainer: UIView = {
        var rightContainer = UIView()
        rightContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return rightContainer
    }()

    var adSoyad: UILabel = {
        var adSoyad = UILabel()
        adSoyad.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        adSoyad.numberOfLines = 0
        adSoyad.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        return adSoyad
    }()

    var unvan: UILabel = {
        var unvan = UILabel()
        unvan.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        unvan.numberOfLines = 0
        unvan.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        return unvan
    }()

    var userImage: UIImageView = {
        var userImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 12, height: 12))
        userImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return userImage
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.addSubview(container)
        container.addSubview(leftContainer) //OK
        container.addSubview(rightContainer) //OK
        leftContainer.addSubview(userImage) //OK
        rightContainer.addSubview(adSoyad)
        rightContainer.addSubview(unvan)

        self.applyConstraints()
    }


    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }

    func applyConstraints()
    {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            container.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 2),
            container.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -2),
            container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 2),
            container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -2),

            leftContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor),
            leftContainer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leftAnchor),
            leftContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor),
            leftContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.12),
            leftContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor),
            leftContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.leftAnchor),

            rightContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor),
            rightContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor),
            rightContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.86),
            rightContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor),
            rightContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.rightAnchor),

            userImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftContainer.topAnchor, constant:2),
            userImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12),
            userImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12),
            userImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftContainer.centerXAnchor),
            userImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: leftContainer.bottomAnchor),

            adSoyad.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.topAnchor, constant: 2),
            adSoyad.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 2),
            adSoyad.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -2),
            adSoyad.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: unvan.topAnchor),

            unvan.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 2),
            unvan.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -2),
            unvan.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: -2),

        ])
    }


    public func adjustSubViews ()
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let katilimci = self.katilimciModel {
                self.adSoyad.text = katilimci.AD ?? ""
                self.unvan.text = katilimci.Ack ?? ""
                self.userImage.image = UIImage(named:"userBlack")
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: So much code... can't you remove as much code as possible while the problem remains and post that code?

Comment: Thanks, I did some trimming.

Comment: Why nesting tableview? what you want?

Comment: I need to show 1 tableView column which each of its cells include a few label, uiview and 1 tableview contanining a list of information about that cell. This barely explains what I really want in the code above.

Comment: @gomozor it would be better if you post the screenshot of UI form simulator or device. may be you don't need nested table view just another custom cell

Answer (score 1):

Firstly change this code:

```
self.addSubview(container)
```

to

```
contentView.addSubview(container)
```

Views in cell should be added to contentView since it is root layout.

Comment: thanks. this may useful in some another parts but didn't work for my code.